# Interpretation of chart in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I built a model of logistic Regression examining whether a customer returns to buy after his first deal by the transaction amount (success is not return..). There are three parameters in the model, a categorical variable indicating the store (6 Parameters for 7 stores), the transaction amount and the interaction between them.
This is the model summary:

```
Call:
glm(formula = NeverReturn ~ factor(Network) + TotalPrice + factor(Network):TotalPrice, 
    family = binomial, data = brill)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-2.690  -0.627  -0.175   0.002   3.825  

Coefficients:
                                Estimate  Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                     3.823802    0.491548    7.78  7.3e-15 ***
factor(Network)51               1.136062    1.314008    0.86   0.3873    
factor(Network)52              -2.460326    0.622006   -3.96  7.6e-05 ***
factor(Network)53              12.200360    4.669899    2.61   0.0090 ** 
factor(Network)71              21.718048    7.475301    2.91   0.0037 ** 
factor(Network)72              16.077374 1187.340238    0.01   0.9892    
factor(Network)73             -21.389871 4387.152411    0.00   0.9961    
TotalPrice                     -0.008737    0.000972   -8.99  < 2e-16 ***
factor(Network)51:TotalPrice   -0.018695    0.005866   -3.19   0.0014 ** 
factor(Network)52:TotalPrice    0.002313    0.001370    1.69   0.0914 .  
factor(Network)53:TotalPrice   -0.030959    0.011234   -2.76   0.0059 ** 
factor(Network)71:TotalPrice   -0.043622    0.015545   -2.81   0.0050 ** 
factor(Network)72:TotalPrice   -0.092994    4.340163   -0.02   0.9829    
factor(Network)73:TotalPrice    0.008737    5.878454    0.00   0.9988    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1405.93  on 1212  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  807.78  on 1199  degrees of freedom
AIC: 835.8

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 16
```

The thing is,
when I plot the charts, the charts of some stores just do not look like logistic regression.
This is the chart:
[image]

and this is the log oodss cart:

[image]
What is right to conclude from that? The model is only true for some stores?

Thank's

---

to generate the charts I inserted the formula of each store into a variable, and then plotted them.
This is my code:

```
TP=seq(from=0, to=1500, by=100)
logodds_10=3.824-0.0087*TP
logodds_51=4.96-0.0274*TP
logodds_52=1.364+0.0064*TP
logodds_53=16.024-0.0397*TP
logodds_71=25.542-0.0349*TP
logodds_72=19.901-0.0843*TP
logodds_73=-17.566+0*TP
p_10=exp(logodds_10)/(1+exp(logodds_10))
p_51=exp(logodds_51)/(1+exp(logodds_51))
p_52=exp(logodds_52)/(1+exp(logodds_52))
p_53=exp(logodds_10)/(1+exp(logodds_53))
p_71=exp(logodds_71)/(1+exp(logodds_71))
p_72=exp(logodds_72)/(1+exp(logodds_72))
p_73=exp(logodds_73)/(1+exp(logodds_73))

 plot(x=TP, y=logodds_10, type="l", col="red", lwd=1,   ylab="Pr(Y=1)" main="LOG ODDS")
 lines(x=TP, y=logodds_51, col="blue", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=logodds_52,   col="pink",  lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=logodds_53,   col="green", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=logodds_71,   col="orange", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=logodds_72,   col="yellow", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=logodds_73,   col="brown", lwd=1) 



  plot(x=TP, y=p_10, type="l", col="red", lwd=1, 
        +  ylab="Pr(Y=1)", main="predicted probabilities")
 lines(x=TP, y=p_51, col="blue", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=p_52,   col="pink",  lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=p_53,   col="green", lwd=1) 
 lines(x=TP, y=p_71,   col="orange", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=p_72,   col="yellow", lwd=1)
 lines(x=TP, y=p_73,   col="brown", lwd=1) 

     legend("bottomright", legend=c("10","51","52","53","71","72","73"), lwd=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),col=c("red", "blue", "pink","green","orange","yellow","brown"))
```

Comment: how did you generate the charts?

Comment: We are not supposed to do code review here but there is an obvious typo in your code for store 53.

Comment: Hint: You can use the `oddsratio` package to simplify your odds analysis

Answer (score -2):

I found it's all mistakes in the plot code..

`loggodds_52` is (`-`) and not (`+`)
and `p_53` calls `logodds_10` instead of `loggodds_53`...

Comment: There isn't going to be anything more to answer this Q, I think. I'm voting *looks OK*.

Comment: @gung the question is "What is right to conclude from that? The model is only true for some stores?". This answer doesn't address that, it reads more like a comment than a full answer.